Access Token Response: Error while extracting response for type
I am getting bellow error message after signing-in to my apringboot application with azure ad-b2c.
[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 
Access Token Response: Error while extracting response for type [class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] 
and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]

Here is my application.properties
spring.application.name=azure B2C SSO Sample

logging.level.org.springframework.security.oauth2=DEBUG

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.client-id=d9353b2a-a3c1-49c2-9252-7xxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.client-secret=Idv8Q~BL1GRyirEaO-AXDaSQgFwJ1Rxxxxx

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.scope=openid,profile


spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.client-authentication-method=client_secret_post
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azuread-b2c.authorization-uri=https://learningakash.b2clogin.com/learningakash.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azuread-b2c.token-uri=https://learningakash.b2clogin.com/learningakash.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/token

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azuread-b2c.jwk-set-uri=https://learningakash.b2clogin.com/learningakash.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=B2C_1_signupsignin


My Security Config.java
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // Secure all requests
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2 // Configure OAuth2 Login
                .authorizationEndpoint(authorization -> 
                    authorization.baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")) // Customize the authorization endpoint
                .redirectionEndpoint(redirection -> 
                    redirection.baseUri("/login/oauth2/code/*")) // Customize the redirection endpoint
            )
            .logout(logout -> 
                logout.logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll() // Redirect to home on logout
            );

        return http.build(); // Return the built HttpSecurity
    }
}

Do I need to create a separate controller function that handles calls after login in
Am I missing something here, whats wrong

Could you try adding app Id too in scope parameter and check if you are getting token or not?

New with azure ad, can you specify more. spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.scope=openid d9353b2a-a3c1-49c2-9252-77f10e8b89b6    Is this what you mean d9353b2a-a3c1-49c2-9252-77f10e8b89b6 is my client-id

@Sridevi Getting this after putting appID The scope 'appId' provided in the request is not supported . Although spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.scope=openid d9353b2a-a3c1-49c2-9252-77f10e8b89b6 worked for me (not sure this is the correct way or not). After Login I was redirected to http://localhost:8080/?continue. This URL is directly resolving index.html. How can I create getmapping so that I can modify this page.

I agree with @Sridevi.
I fixed the issue by adding the Client ID to the scope and the redirect-uri should be as shown below.
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.scope=openid,<clientID>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azuread-b2c

Below is the complete code to obtain an access token with authentication to Azure AD B2C.
SecurityConfig.java :
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .authorizationEndpoint(authorization ->
                                authorization.baseUri("/oauth2/authorization")
                        )
                        .redirectionEndpoint(redirection ->
                                redirection.baseUri("/login/oauth2/code/*")
                        )
                        .tokenEndpoint(token ->
                                token.accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient())
                        )
                )
                .logout(logout ->
                        logout.logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient() {
        return new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
    }
}

HomeController.java :
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;
    public HomeController(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        this.authorizedClientService = authorizedClientService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
        if (authentication != null) {
            OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                    authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                    authentication.getName()
            );
            if (authorizedClient != null) {
                OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();
                model.addAttribute("accessToken", accessToken.getTokenValue());
                model.addAttribute("user", authentication.getPrincipal().getAttributes());
                System.out.println("Access Token: " + accessToken.getTokenValue());
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("user", null);
            }
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("user", null);
        }
        return "home";
    }
}

home.html :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<div th:if="${user == null}">
    <p>You are not logged in. Please <a href="/oauth2/authorization/azuread-b2c">login with Azure AD B2C</a>.</p>
</div>
<div th:if="${user != null}">
    <p>You are logged in!</p>
    <p>User Information:</p>
    <pre th:text="${user}"></pre>
    <p>Access Token: <span th:text="${accessToken}">No Access Token Available.</span></p>

    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <button type="submit">Logout</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

application.properties :
server.port=8080
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.client-id=<clientID>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.scope=openid,<clientID>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azuread-b2c
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azuread-b2c.client-name=Azure AD B2C
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azuread-b2c.authorization-uri=https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyName>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azuread-b2c.token-uri=https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyName>/oauth2/v2.0/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azuread-b2c.jwk-set-uri=https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyName>/discovery/v2.0/keys

I added the below URL in AppRegistration -> Authentication -> Single-page application Redirect URL.
http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azuread-b2c


Output :
I got the following output in the browser and successfully signed in by clicking the Login with Azure AD B2C button.



